# Different ways to post json values to Server

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, wcf

> i have created a login WCF service that is tested successfully using fiddler and postman tool..!

[image: json post test]

> If the login process is success then WCF will give the json message as above screenshot.
>   But when i posted username and password from android it gives the result as [{"message":"not created","success":-1}].i cant figure it out where the bug actually is.!!
>   i am providing the corresponding android code and logcat below.please help me
>   If the login process is success then WCF will give the json message as above screenshot.
>
> But when i posted username and password from android it gives the result as [{"message":"not created","success":-1}].i cant figure it out where the bug actually is.!!
>
> i am providing the corresponding android code and logcat below.please help me
>
> If the login process is success then WCF will give the json message as above screenshot.
>
> But when i posted username and password from android it gives the result as [{"message":"not created","success":-1}].i cant figure it out where the bug actually is.!!
>
> i am providing the corresponding android code and logcat below.please help me

[image: Logcat]

> below is webservice code in android

[image]

Comment: Post code as text, not as images. Images can't be searched or copied and pasted and are difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code:-

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 60000);
            HttpResponse response;

    try
    {

            JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
            j.put("UserName", "hiqmaali");
            j.put("Password", "qwerty");
        Messages.onLowmemory();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(HOST_URL);

        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(j.toString(), "UTF-8");
        post.setEntity(stringEntity);

        response = client.execute(post);
```

In your case send json to server so u have to try above way.